Why is this trasnformation with the proj cct program resulting in file not found error?

I'm using proj v8.1.1 that was downloaded and compiled for C++.
I tried setting PROJ_NETWORK=ON as a bash variable which didn't
affect outcome.
I've also manually downloaded us_noaa_conus.tif into
a directory and set the PROJ_DATA variable to the path to the
directory containing the grid which didn't affect the outcome.
The following command was submitted using a bash shell on the RHEL8 OS.

echo 32.804191 -117.258911 0 | PROJ_NETWORK=ON cct -d 8 --verbose +proj=pipeline +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad +step +proj=hgridshift +grids=us_noaa_conus.tif +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
proj_create: Error 1029 (File not found or invalid): pipeline: Pipeline: Bad step definition: proj=hgridshift (File not found or invalid)
cct: Bad transformation arguments - (File not found or invalid)
I thought it might have something to do with the us_noaa_conus.tif since I don't see that within my proj download of v8.1.1 or v9.4.1 but the error is calling out the proj=hgridshift step.
I copied the proj pipeline command from https://epsg.io/15851

Have you tried downloading the gridshift file manually from https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ-data/tree/master/us_noaa? Put the file into your PROJ_DATA directory.

I have not, but I'm confused about how GDAL 1.10 was able to produce a transformation result that supposedly matches what this method provides and I had never downloaded that before when using GDAL 1.10.  This is my first time trying to use PROJ directly so I am obviously confused about how this is supposed to work.

Also I thought that the PROJ_NETWORK=ON was supposed to allow network access to find the grids.

I do not know Linux well. I thought the environmental variables are set with "export". Anyway, by placing the gridshift file into proj_data manually avoids possible network issues. GDAL 1.10 is eleven years old, it is unrealistic to believe that all things still work in the same way.

export should only be needed if subsequently starting a subshell but I also tried that to no effect.  I also downloaded the entire proj_data zip with all of the grids, unzipped it, and set PROJ_DATA to that directory and it still didn't find the file.

I understand that things change over time, but there should be an explanation for that which I need to know.  My guess is that the method GDAL is picking for NAD27 to WGS84 transformation has changed and I need to know why so I need to get proj working with grids until I found an output that matches what GDAL 3.4.2 and GDAL 1.1.0 are producing.

Maybe the old GDAL is using old Proj (Proj4)? There was a huge change in Proj some years ago https://www.osgeo.org/foundation-news/announcing-proj-6-0-0/.

I had a try on Windows, Proj version 9.4.0 installed with OSGeo4W. The gridshift file was already in the proj_data directory and your command returned
32.80423938   -117.25978145    0.00000000           inf. I tried also with Conda by installing GDAL into a new env, and that worked without issues, too. So obviously you have some installation problem that you must fix first.

To be clear, how did you define the PROJ_DATA directory?  Did you set the PROJ_DATA variable to the path or is there some other way? This behavior you observed is the default for NAD27 to WGS84 transform using GDAL 1.10 and PROJ 4.4.9 and I don't remember installing any grid shift files.  It appears to me that the default behavior of GDAL 3.4.2 and PROJ 8.1.1 is worse and is using a less precise method by default. These results you provided are exactly what I get using GDAL 1.10 and PROJ 4.4.9 without supplying any grid shift file or proj pipeline explicitly.

I have PROJ_DATA set with an environmental variable PROJ_DATA=C:\OSGeo4W\share\proj. Conda has it in PROJ_DATA=C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\envs\gdaltest\Library\share\proj

On a side issue, I don't think you need to use the 2nd step or at least not all the parameters. Just set the output units to deg in the first step.
